# "a" vs "an" before parenthesis: which indefinite article should I use when adding parentheses before the subject?

Tags: indefinite-articles, parentheses, vowels

I want to write a remark in parenthesis between an indefinite article and the rest of the subject. If I didn't write this clarification then using the "*a*" article would be correct; however for the clarification alone "*an*" should be used.

Which one of the following examples is correct? Both sound weird to my ears.

> This experiment used *an* (arguably small) set of data.
>
> This experiment used *a* (arguably small) set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading both versions out aloud. You'll hear that 'an' sounds much better.

Answer (score -1):

To be true, ' arguably small ' is not parenthetical. It's a determiner of ' set of data ', and for that matter, an adjective phrase. Articles precede such determiners so use of 'an ' would be correct.

Comment: 'Arguably small' is certainly being used as a  parenthetical (additional information added as an aside) here. In << This experiment used an arguably small set of data. >> it's not. Contrast << The experiment **did** use a set of data. OK, arguably, it was small. >> with << The set of data the experiment used might be considered small. >>

Comment: To view 'arguably small' as parenthesis ( interpolation) would demand use of an 'a' as it's an en extra.

Comment: No; the a/an choice is totally dependent on facilitation of reading, which trumps matters of grammar, shibboleths about the need for no changes to be necessary to the matrix sentence when a parenthetical is omitted.... This has been covered comprehensively before on ELU (and this trumps other rules hereabouts).